# PHP AJAX JQUERY : return php error and show the error in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to show php error in jQuery Ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "php/verifyName.php", 
    data: {
        'name':name
    }, // données à transmettre
    dataType: "json",       
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {                      
        if(xhr.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 0)
            valid = true;
        else if(xhr.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 2) {
            alert("Erreur dans la verification !");
            valid = false;
        }  
        else if(xhr.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 1) {
            alert("Le nom choisie existe deja, veuillez choisir un autre nom !");
            valid = false;
        }   
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        alert ("Oops: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

php files contains :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
...
if($nb != 0) {
    header("NB_SUCCESS: 1"); 
} else {
    header("NB_SUCCESS: 0"); 
}
```

when i debug in firebug, i never access to method sucess(data) for 2 cases

i try it also in chrome, that's same, i jump directly last };

Also, new code with jquery 1.10 not work like this :

php file :

```
$name_exists = array('error'=>false,'nb'=>$nb);
echo json_encode($name_exists);
```

and js code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/verifyName.php",
    data: { 'name':nameRecette },
    dataType: "json",
})
.done(function(data) { 
console.log(data.nb); 
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
console.log('error');   
}).always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

not work also

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using, because there were some changes in versions after 1.8 that modify how you are supposed to handle success call backs.

Comment: I would suggest giving a JSON response. It's native to JS and a more standard way of approaching it.

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.10

Comment: i've change code like this, doesn't work :

.done(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
     if(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 0)
        valid = true;
      else if(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 2) {
        alert("Erreur dans la verification !");
        valid = false;
      }  
      else if(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 1) {
        alert("Le nom choisie existe deja, veuillez choisir un autre nom !");
        valid = false;
      } 
    });

Comment: this code also not work :

.done(function(data) { console.log(data); })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
     if(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 0)
        valid = true;
      else if(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 2) {
        alert("Erreur dans la verification de la recette !");
        valid = false;
      }  
      else if(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 1) {
        alert("Le nom de la recette choisie existe deja, veuillez choisir un autre nom !");
        valid = false;
      } 
    }).always(function() { alert("complete"); });

Answer (score 0):

If you reference http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you will find about half-way down a yellow box labelled "Deprecated" which indicates that after jQuery 1.8 "success" is no longer a valid callback for $.ajax.

The proper method is (per the same page):

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

If you remove it your response will be fine. If you really need this header then you should return a proper JSON response like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json'); 
echo json_encode('test');
die();
```

Plus in your javascript condition

```
if(xhr.getResponseHeader("NB_SUCCESS") == 2)
```

seems to be unnecessary as header is either set to 1 or 0 in your php code.